# Regex email check not working correctly

Tags: regex

I have a problem with my regex. I didn't test this before. I have the following regex:

```
^(?:(?:[a-z])+(.|_)?(?!\.))*\w@(?:(?:[a-z])+(-|.)?(?!\.))*\w\.\w{2,}$
```

Now, my email validation halfly works. Here are some tests (according to regex101):

```
test -- invalid
test@ -- invalid
test@test -- invalid
test@test. -- invalid
test@test.de -- valid
test@test.de. -- invalid
test@test@test.com -- valid
test...test@test.com -- invalid
```

So, more than one `@` can be used which is invalid for an email.

I kind of cannot see what I'm doing wrong.

NOTE:

I know there's a stackoverflow question that has a method on how to validate email with regex, HOWEVER: I'd like to know what I did wrong so I can learn from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I'd rather know what I did wrong so I can learn from it.

Comment: @MauricePerry Forgot to add a `,`; my bad.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem myself. The following regex does work:

```
^(?:(?:\w)+(\.|_)?(?!\.))*\w@(?:(?:[a-z])+(-|\.)?(?!\.))*[a-z]\.[a-z]{2,}$
```

I changed `(.|_)` into `(\.|_)` and `(-|.)` into `(-|\.)` to use `.` literally as a period and not as an 'all character "wildcard"'. I changed `\w\.\w{2,}` in `[a-z]\.[a-z]{2,}` to disallow `_` in the last part.

Comment: `(\.|_)` is better replaced with `[._]`. And no need escaping the dot then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the tip.